# How to enable twin mouse pointers / dual mouse pointers

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the idea, I have two area on the webpage I want the actions in one area to be identical in the other, it this possible and how would I go about it?

More detail:

We have 2 `<div>`s: `<div id='section1'>` and `<div id='section2'>`

There will be a check box to enable dual mouse mode.

When the main mouse pointer moves into either of these divs a 'twin' mouse pointer is in the other div and performs the same actions.

The interface is coded in php/html, I'm assuming this will require javascript (jQuery?) currently implemented for menus.

Where do I begin, any pointers/suggestions?

Comment: Is there an absolute need to have two pointers or would it be sufficient if the same actions were performed in the other section?

Comment: FYI. Since this question doesn't have anything to do with PHP, I removed that tag.

Comment: Are you talking about mirroring input from a single input device, or actually handling two separate physical inputs? If you just need to mirror mouse movements and interactions from a single device, then you can add a handler for every capability and duplicate a cursor that you can then animate. For interactions with `#section2` you will have to check the target elements at the specific coordinate to see what actions they afford. Your code would then relay/proxy the action. If the panes are identical then this would be easier.

Comment: @El_Vanja It would be preferable to have the pointer displayed in the other section, but would also be acceptable if it wasn't.

Comment: @RoAchterberg A single input device, one mouse. The two panes (divs) will have identical construction, they may display different content but the functionality will be identical. So it is possible, next to figure out how to achieve it, code wise.

Comment: You should have an idea of where to start now. If you need additional input then please share some code you've tried.